# Rails datetime_field how to remove specific weekday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a datetime field at my views:

```
 <%= form.datetime_field :start_time, selected: Date.today, min: 0.days.ago, max: 1.year.from_now%>
```

It allows user to select date and time only from today's day and go max to one year. So I have a question - if I can specify min and max for days in the year, can I do the same for the weekdays? For example - disable ability to choose Sundays on calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this through HTML/rails, you need to add some javascript.

Using jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('input[name="datetime"]').on('input', function(e){
  let day = new Date($(this).val()).getDay();
  if([# of the weekday you want to avoid].includes(day)){
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Checkout [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) for the days of the week in integers.